# Is this a normal behavior for a TransactionEventHandler?

Tags: java, neo4j

Neo4j version is 2.2.1.

Here's the code:

```
AtomicInteger afterCommitCallCounter = new AtomicInteger(0);
AtomicInteger beforeCommitCallCounter = new AtomicInteger(0);
db().registerTransactionEventHandler(new TransactionEventHandler.Adapter<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void afterCommit(TransactionData data, Void state) {
        afterCommitCallCounter.incrementAndGet();
    }
    @Override
    public Void beforeCommit(TransactionData data) throws Exception {
        beforeCommitCallCounter.incrementAndGet();
        return null;
    }
});
Node n;
try (final Transaction tx = db().beginTx()) {
    n = db().createNode();
    tx.success();
}
try (final Transaction tx = db().beginTx()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        n.setProperty("" + i, i);
    }
    tx.success();
}
System.out.println(afterCommitCallCounter);  // 102
System.out.println(beforeCommitCallCounter); // 102
```

And here's the excerpt from the manual:

> If `beforeCommit` is successfully executed the transaction will be
>   committed and the `afterCommit` method will be called with the same
>   transaction data as well as the object returned from `beforeCommit`.

So, my question: why is `afterCommit` being called 102 times? I thought that commit is performed once - during the call to `Transaction#close`. I.e. it has to be called 2 times tops, but in this case the handler is being notified on each `Node#setProperty` call. I didn't find a clear explanation in docs for this.

By the way, if you comment out the `tx.success()` in the second try-block, the result will be 101 for both counters, so these are definitely `setProperty` calls that generate all this events, but why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you create a new property key (or node label for that matter), the transaction event handler methods will be called (both before and after commit). It is strange, indeed, but it is apparently by design.

See https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/1320 for more info.

Comment: Well, this is weird. I mean, those microtransactions pop up in event handlers, but seems like their TransactionData is empty. hmm... I'll mark your answer as a solution though, thank you!

Comment: They are empty, indeed. Thus weird, though not incorrect. Cheers!

Comment: I can't agree completely on that since I'd exect a micro-transaction which is a result of `setProperty` to either result in *not* triggering events or trigger an event which reflects in a `TransactionData`'s `assigned properties` counter.